# Ошибка при запросе к базе данных через ООП

Tags: php, ооп, mysqli

Есть подключение к базе данных в файле db_connect.php

```
        public function connect(){
            $this->con = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
            if(!$this->con){
                throw new Exception('error connect');
            }
        }
```

В файле index.php никаких ошибок и все проходит отлично ,а вот в файле page.php при таком коде выдает ошибку

```
include("db_connect.php");
    $db = new Database ;
    $db->connect() ;
    $page = $_GET['id'];
    echo $page;
    $query = mysqli_query($db->connect(),"SELECT * FROM article WHERE Id='$page'");
```

Ошибка :  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db_article-master\page.php on line 7

Comment: и что же ты передаешь первым аргументом в mysqli_query по твоему мнению?

Comment: Подключение к базе данных?

Comment: какое подключение? а как оно туда попадёт? у тебя connect что-то возвращает?)

Comment: Спасибо,вот теперь все понятно)

Comment: Все ещё непонятно, зачем здесь класс database с функцией connect